# jQuery animate won't slide width, but will toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to get jQuery to animate with slide rather than toggle. I have these files included in my HTML `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery:

```
// $item is a list gathered as $('#gallery ul li') and all output to console as should
// $prev will be used to get current li width, but not to worry about for now.
$.fn.slider = function($item,$prev){
        $item.each(function(i){
            $(this).animate({width:'slide',left:'-= 500'});
        });
    };
```

What I don't understand is if I change the animate width from slide to toggle, it will work, but with the slide, nothing happens. I tested at jsfiddle, and the slide works there. What's the deal? What am I missing that jsfiddle has?

Edit: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robx/ZvKUW/1/

Comment: Have you tried running your local copy in Firefox with Firebug enabled to see if there are any javascript errors during runtime?

Comment: I am looking at it yes otherwise i would not know if $item contained anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://api.jquery.com/animate/

> *In addition to numeric values, each
>   property can take the strings 'show',
>   'hide',  and 'toggle'. These shortcuts
>   allow for custom hiding and showing
>   animations that take into account the
>   display type of the element.*

Note that `'slide'` isn't mentioned, therefore it's ignored.

Comment: Oh interesting, I though I could use other features from the JQuery UI. Thanks for pointing that out ;)

Comment: Weird, though, even without the width animate, it should still move left, but is doing nothing.